# Error when running brew cask install

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew-cask

Here's the error:

> $ brew cask install sublime-text
>   Error: No such file or directory -brew-cask

Comment: What is that command supposed to do?

Comment: brew aka "Homebrew" installs system packages... brew cask installs GUI apps/regular OSX programs from the command line.  So, you can automate the downloading and installing of DMG and zip files.  Check out: https://mug.im/blog/2013/06/22/manage-your-mac-apps-with-homebrew-cask/

Answer (score 1):

`brew cask install` was working earlier in the day, so I hoping that it was just a change in the load path affected the shell's ability to find and run the `brew cask install` command.

So, I did an exhaustive search:

```
$ find / \( -name "brew\-cask*" -type f \) -or \( -ilname "*brew-cask*" \) 2>/dev/null | grep brew-cask | xargs ls -l

-rw-r--r--  1 lex  admin    0 Sep  1 16:42 /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/brew-cask.brewing
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lex  admin  193 Aug 31 20:35 /Library/Caches/Homebrew/brew-cask--git/bin/brew-cask.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 lex  admin  470 Aug 31 20:35 /Library/Caches/Homebrew/brew-cask--git/brew-cask.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lex  wheel  197 Sep  1 16:39 /usr/local/Cellar/brew-cask/0.15.0/bin/brew-cask.rb
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lex  admin   32 Aug 31 20:35 /usr/local/Library/Formula/brew-cask.rb -> ../Taps/phinze-cask/brew-cask.rb
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lex  admin   29 Sep  1 16:39 /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/brew-cask -> ../../Cellar/brew-cask/0.15.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lex  admin  193 Aug 31 20:35 /usr/local/Library/Taps/phinze-cask/bin/brew-cask.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 lex  admin  470 Aug 31 20:35 /usr/local/Library/Taps/phinze-cask/brew-cask.rb
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lex  admin   43 Sep  1 16:39 /usr/local/bin/brew-cask.rb -> ../Cellar/brew-cask/0.15.0/bin/brew-cask.rb
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lex  admin   26 Sep  1 16:39 /usr/local/opt/brew-cask -> ../Cellar/brew-cask/0.15.0
```

The last two lines looked interesting...

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/brew-cask/0.15.0/bin/brew-cask.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lex  wheel  197 Sep  1 16:39 /usr/local/Cellar/brew-cask/0.15.0/bin/brew-cask.rb

$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/brew-cask/0.15.0
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  421 lex  wheel  14314 Sep  1 16:39 Casks
-rw-r--r--    1 lex  admin    226 Sep  1 16:39 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--    1 lex  wheel   1909 Sep  1 16:39 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    3 lex  wheel    102 Sep  1 16:39 bin
drwxr-xr-x    5 lex  wheel    170 Sep  1 16:39 rubylib
```

Hmmm... `/usr/local/opt/brew-cask` points to a directory that contains a bin directory that then contains brew-cask...

Then, I looked in at my load path...

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/lex/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/Users/lex/.rbenv/bin:/Users/lex/.rbenv/shims:/Users/lex/bin:/usr/local/opt:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

And sure enough, my PATH had been changed to load files in `/usr/local/opt` before it loads files in /usr/local/bin.

The rest of the "executables" were similar in the  `/usr/local/opt` directory.  So, I removed it from my path.

I tried again...

```
$ brew cask install sublime-text
==> Downloading http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime%20Text%202.0.2.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Success! sublime-text installed to /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/sublime-text/2.0.2
==> Linking Sublime Text 2.app to /Users/lex/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app
```

Success :-)